# Setting precision in Java

Tags: java

If I want a double to have 9 decimal places, do I have to convert it to a string and then back to a double to do this (string methods are the only methods I'm seeing for setting the precision)?. In any case, what is the conventional way for setting the precision for a double if, for example, I want my method to return a double with 9 decimal places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting confused between a double's internal representation and it's display. Internally double numbers are always stored the same way but you can of course use a formater like [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) to return 9 decimal points from your double number.

Answer (score 1):

Use Big Decimal to get 9 decimal places

or

```
double d = 1.2345672626346;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#########");
System.out.print(df.format(d));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't control precision with primitives in Java. You need to use `BigDecimal`. Read [this excellent tutorial](http://www.opentaps.org/docs/index.php/How_to_Use_Java_BigDecimal%3a_A_Tutorial)..

Answer (score 0):

You could also use:

```
DecimalFormat df = DecimalFormat.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
df.setMinimumFractionDigits(9);  //sets 9 digits after the '.'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String formatedString = String.format("%.2f");
```

it set the presition to 5 digit o any.

if you only want to print it use this way.

```
System.out.printf("%.5f",123.2342622467);
```